# Freeze several threads in a parallel for loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, debugging, parallel-processing

Normally, if I would debug through a `multi threading process`, I select every thread except one and freeze it. How I can do this in a parallel for loop? If I freeze threads, another thread will be spawn automatically. Is there a way to do this without `new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1 }`? Thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean by freeze threads? and why do you need it? Sounds like the [XYProblem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) for me. You're better off asking the original question.

Comment: With freezing I mean, that I can pause while debugging in Visual Studio a specific thread. Why I need it? Debugging with several threads at the same time isn't very funny.

Comment: That's a good question. I don't know the answer for it(+1); I usually feel comfortable with debugging with multiple threads. As soon as the breakpoint hits you should disable the BP. so that you follow only one thread not a bunch of them. That makes me comfortable with debugging multi threaded app.

Comment: _"If I freeze threads, another thread will be spawn automatically"_ -- it's not clear what you mean by this. It's true that the TPL will add new threads to the workload, but only to the extent it would normally; freezing a thread in the debugger shouldn't affect that (too much...slow running threads do cause thread pool to add new threads if you don't constrain parallelism). In any case, the question isn't very clear without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that illustrates exactly what you're trying to accomplish.